# jQuery toggle not toggling

Tags: jquery, toggle, hide, show, html-lists

I have a page with a bunch of fake dropdown menus that are coded like this (I can't really change the HTML):

```
<div class="select">
    <div class="wrapper calcdropdown">
        <a href="#" class="dd-openercalc">Select a calculator</a>
        <a href="#" class="dd-opener pulldown-arrow">&nbsp;</a>
    </div>
    <ul class="selectbox">
        <li>Dropdown item 1</li>
        <li>Dropdown item 2</li>
        <li>Dropdown item 3</li>
    <ul>
</div>
```

When I click on either of the links inside the calcdropdown DIVs I need to toggle the corresponding selectbox UL. When I use toggle() the selectbox UL appears when I first click the links but doesn't disappear when I click the links again.

```
var $j = jQuery.noConflict();
$j(document).ready(function() {
    // hide all the dropdowns by default
    $j(".selectbox").hide();

    $j('.calcdropdown a').live('click',function(e) {
        // hide the dropdowns in case another one's open
        $j(".selectbox").hide();
        var self = $j(this);
        // show the selectbox for this link
        var thisSelectbox = $j(this).parents('.select').children('.selectbox').toggle();
        e.preventDefault();
    });
});
```

This doesn't work, either:

```
var $j = jQuery.noConflict();
$j(document).ready(function() {
    $j(".selectbox").hide();

    $j('.calcdropdown a').live('click',function(e) {
        $j(".selectbox").hide();
        var self = $j(this);
        var thisSelectbox = $j(this).parents('.select').children('.selectbox');
        if(thisSelectbox.is(':hidden')) {
            thisSelectbox.show();
        } else {
            thisSelectbox.hide();
        }
    });
});
```

How can I hide the selectboxes after I show them?

Comment: Depending on your menu structure, this might be because of the `parents()` call. Have you tried using `closest('.select')` instead?

Comment: Changing that doesn't make a difference.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Remove `$j(".selectbox").hide();` from the click-function.

Otherwise you always do this steps inside the click-function:

1. hide the element
2. toggle the element(makes it visible all the time,  because you hide it before)

**Edit:**(I didn't realize that you use more than one of those elements)

To hide all .selectbox except the one related to the click use not():

```
var $j = jQuery.noConflict();
$j(document).ready(function() {
    // hide all the dropdowns by default
    $j(".selectbox").hide();

    $j('.calcdropdown a').live('click',function(e) {

        var target=$j(this).parents('.select').children('.selectbox');
            $j('.selectbox').not(target.toggle()).hide();
            e.preventDefault();
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/doktormolle/qG8ps/

Comment: +1: To expand, `hide()` is hiding the elements you're toggling on so it's hiding and then showing those elements so quickly you can't see what's happening.

Comment: Well spotted. If you want to still hide the elements from other menus, use your first example, but swap out `toggle()` for `show()`.

Comment: That toggles the selectbox that corresponds to the link I click, but it doesn't work if I've opened a selectbox elsewhere on the page. If any other selectboxes are showing I need to hide them before showing this one.

Comment: Changing toggle() to show() doesn't hide the selectbox when I click a second time.

Answer (score 2):

From your comments on the other answer, you're after a solution that:

1. Hides all other menus
2. Toggles the visibility of the currently clicked menu

It's a bit messy, but if you change `$j(".selectbox").hide();` in your first example to `$j(".selectbox").not($j(this).parents('.select').children('.selectbox')).hide();`, you should get the behaviour you're after.

This hides all `.selectbox` elements except the one that corresponds to the current link. Then, your call to `toggle()` should work as expected.